# Paste colors but not font in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing technical documentation for which I will need to copy a lot of code, often at a line per line rate like this:

*Some descriptional text*

```
var date = DateTime.Now();
```

*Some descriptional text*

```
var result = CallSomeFunction();
```

I need to keep the coloring intact, while using the font of the document, not the original (as copied from Visual Studio).

As I am copying (usually) a limited number of lines, at intervals, I would need to select each block of code manually and reset the font.

Over the course of the document (which will be easily 50+ pages), this will prove very inefficient. Especially if I have to use the mouse every single time.

**The question**

Is there a *paste special* option that will do the above (keep color, not font)?

**An alternative**

If the answer to the above is no, is there a way to record a macro that would select the code I just pasted, and set the font to the one of the document, using some key shortcut combination?

Comment: Just in case you hadn't considered this: Is the font that is pasted in different from any fonts that you actually use in your document? If so, another approach might be to paste everything in, then do a single Find/Replace that looks for that font and replaces it everywhere by the one you want.

Comment: My bet would be it is completely different. Would be an option!

Comment: Would be an alternative only solution, but any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: In the Replace dialog box, ensure that you are seeing the full dialog (i.e. click the "More >>" button if you see it. With the insertion point in the Find What box, click the Format button at the botttom left, choose Font, then select the font you want to replace. Then click in the Replace With box, and use the same method to pick the font you want to replace with. Then Replace!

Comment: If the destination document is supposed to be all the same font, when you've finished your cutting & pasting just select the whole document and change the font in one fell swoop.

Comment: @mcalex: I need to change the font size as well, I would change too much like that (sadly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't received an alternative solution, I will accept the following as an answer:

> In the Replace dialog box, ensure that you are seeing the full dialog
>   (i.e. click the "More >>" button if you see it. With the insertion
>   point in the Find What box, click the Format button at the botttom
>   left, choose Font, then select the font you want to replace. Then
>   click in the Replace With box, and use the same method to pick the
>   font you want to replace with. Then Replace!

Full credit goes to [bibadia](https://superuser.com/users/181946/bibadia).